# R for loop Error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, for-loop, smoothing, spline

Updated: @Parfait pointed out a silly typo that I made. However, a new issue is that I expect the `optim.spar` to return a decimal value (for example 0.372) but the codes return me a list that contains 4 numbers as below.

```
[[1]]
[1] 15 25 55 85
```

Anyone could please point out what is wrong this time? Thanks

---

Please help me fix this for loop.

To download the data type the following commands, noting that "username" and "password" needs to be replaced by your logging information from the Human Mortality Database. You can go to website https://mortality.org/ and create the account (will take less than 30s).

```
library(demography)
library(splines)

#Read Japan mortality data from the Human Mortality Database
JPNmort <- hmd.mx("JPN","username","password")

age = 2:110

data1= cbind(1:109, 
                 JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2016"], 
                 JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2016"])
data2 = cbind(1:109, 
                   JPNmort[["rate"]][["total"]][age, "2017"],
                   JPNmort[["pop"]][["total"]][age, "2017"])



#Reformat data rows and columns
column.names = c("Age", "mu_x", "Ec_x")
rownames(data1) = NULL
rownames(data2) = NULL

colnames(data1) = column.names
colnames(data2) = column.names

spars.values <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.001)
hyper_param_spars = expand.grid(spars.values, 
                                c(0))
colnames(hyper_param_spars) = c("spar", "Error.Rate")

# list to store the results
sm.spar <- vector("list", nrow(hyper_param_spars))
sm.spline <- vector("list", nrow(hyper_param_spars))

for(i in 1:nrow(hyper_param_spars)) {
  
  sm.spar[[i]] <- unlist(hyper_param_spars[i, 1])
  sm.spline[[i]] <- smooth.spline(training[, "Age"], 
                                  training[, "mu_x"], 
                                  spar = sm.spar[[i]] )


  # MSE
  hyper_param_spars$Error.Rate[i] <- mean((validation[, "mu_x"] - fitted(sm.spline[[i]]) )^2)
}

Error in data1[, "Ages"] : subscript out of bounds

# optimal spar 
optim.spar = hyper_param[which.min(hyper_param_spars$Error.Rate),1]
```

As I keep getting Error message 'Error in data1[, "Ages"] : subscript out of bounds'

Comment: This may just be a typo. The `column.names` at beginning contains *Age* not *Age**s***

Comment: Thank you @Parfait ! Fixed the codes, I just updated my question as there is a new issue coming up, any chance that you could have a look at? Thanks

Comment: Please post a new question with a [mre] and delete this one. Right now, this post with same original text, error message, and title will confuse current and future readers between earlier and updated issue.